# Javascript object won't work in 'if' statement

Tags: javascript, object

I am a novice javascript programmer and am trying to create a little text game.  Basically the user is supposed to type in the name of a ship when prompted and depending what ship they choose will let them dock in the harbor.  The problem is I can't seem to get my if statement to work correctly so that the object of ShipTypes is used properly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
window.alert("Greetings sea traveller. You have sailed many long days across the ocean and now it is time to dock your ship into port. But you must choose the correct mooring for the size of your vessel.");

window.prompt("Please choose from the following ships: Carrier, Destroyer, or a Sloop" .toLowerCase());

var harbor = 30;

function ShipType (shipName,shipType,shipLength,shipHull,shipKeelDepth) {
    "use strict";
    this.shipName = shipName;
    this.shipType = shipType;
    this.shipLength = shipLength;
    this.shipHull = shipHull;
    this.shipKeelDepth = shipKeelDepth;
}

var carrier = new ShipType ("The Enterprise","Carrier",200,"Steel",80);
var destroyer = new ShipType ("The Dragon","Destroyer",170,"Steel",65);
var sloop = new ShipType ("The Sunray","Sloop",120,"Hybrid",25);

/*window.alert(sloop.shipKeelDepth);*/

if(ShipType.shipKeelDepth <= harbor){
    window.alert("You may enter the harbor! ");
}
else {
    window.alert("You may not enter our harbor as your ship is the wrong size!");  
}
```

Comment: Your `if` statement should be examining the keel depth property on one of the ship instances you created, not on the ShipType constructor function itself.

Comment: `ShipType` is a constructor. There is no `.shipKeelDepth` property in your constructor function.

Comment: @Jason D'Amico Also, I'd call the object just `ship` instead of `shipType`

Comment: `"use strict";` should go at the top of your program, not in a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to access the properties on the constructor function.
You need to access it on your instances of that constructor.

Edited to help with your comment below. "what if I had 100 ships".

Well that would be great of course. Anyway, you can put a method on your constructor like so:

You also need to track harbor some how, whether that be in the model itself or elsewhere.

```js
ShipType.prototype.checkKeelDepth = function () {
  if (this.shipKeelDepth <= this.harbor) {
     // do something 
  }
}

const someShipType = new ShipType(...args)
someShipType.checkKeelDepth()
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.  I did try this and it worked.

But wouldn't that be redundant?  Wouldn't I have to make a bunch of 'if' statements for each variable?   What if I had 100 ships?

Comment: Why don't you create a method on your constructor prototype that checks the shipKneelDepth. It can then be used on all instances, and inherited further.

Comment: Senojoet;  can you show me an example of the method?

Comment: I've edited my answer, hopefully its more informative.

Answer (score 2):

Try using one of the actual ship names in the if statement. For instance:

```
if(carrier.shipKeelDepth <= harbor){
    window.alert("You may enter the harbor! ");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `ShipType` which is a `constructor` not `object`.
You can do the following thing instead

```
if(carrier.shipKeelDepth <= harbor){
    window.alert("You may enter the harbor! ");
}
```

Or

```
if(destroyer.shipKeelDepth <= harbor){
    window.alert("You may enter the harbor! ");
}
```

Or

```
if(sloop.shipKeelDepth <= harbor){
    window.alert("You may enter the harbor! ");
}
```

Comment: This works.  But now every instance is allowed to dock.  How do I code it so that a var is checked for keel size and if it doesn't pass it goes to the 'else' statement?

Comment: You can define function inside `constructor`.  For more you can read [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_constructors.asp)